# How to disable CKeditor <p> tag from modification

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in my web application and need to disable/enable the html tags from javascript or i can use the CKEditor Add-on.

**Example**

```
<textarea name="editor1">
<div>
User Can modify this 
</div>

<div class="disabled" readonly="readonly">
           Read only Div
</div>
</textarea>
```

Customize JQuery not working

```
 CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].on('contentDom', function() {
    this.document.on('click', function(event){
         //your code
        alert('Click Event');
         $('.disabled :input').attr('disabled', true);

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create non-editable div's or paragraphs or any selected text by adding the placeholder plugin.

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/placeholder

However the placeholder plugin requires some other plugins also installed for it to work. When you click "Download" a modal appears. At the bottom it shows the Add-on dependencies which also need to be uploaded to the plugin directory, AND added into the config.js file.

```
// example config.js
config.extraPlugins = "placeholder,widget,lineutils,dialog,clipboard, ... {plus-other-dependent-plugins-as-needed}";
```

You do not need to identify the div's or paragraphs or anything else in any special way, i.e. readonly="readonly" is not necessary. The plugin handles it.